# Looking for 2 legal terms

Tags: usage

I'm looking for legalese.

1. breach of fiduciary trust (fiduciary basically means, as an adjective, 'having financial responsibility for someone else's money' from Latin 'fidere' trust)
2. negligence

For 1. I have 违背受托责任 and for 2. I have 玩忽职守 but I have no way of knowing if these are in fact the terms a Chinese lawyer might use.

Are they acceptable? Any improvements welcome!

Answer (score 1):

**New Century E-C**

*fiduciary*

> (of trust or trustee)
>
> 受信托的；与受托人有关的
>
> They have a case against their directors for breach of fiduciary duty.
>
> 他们掌握了足够的证据控告董事不履行信托责任。

*negligence*

> (civil wrong)
>
> 过失(行为)；疏忽
>
> They tried to sue for negligence.
>
> 他们试图就过失行为提起诉讼。

**C&T Biz**

*negligence*

> 过失 guòshī
>
> negligence clause
>
> 过失免责条款
>
> guòshī miǎnzé tiáokuǎn
>
> negligence liability insurance
>
> 过失责任保险
>
> guòshī zérèn bǎoxiǎn

**21st Century**

negligence

> 【法律】 过失的 [1300∼1350]

Answer (score 1):

1. There is a  背信罪 (Literally, it means the crime of breach trust ) for breach of fiduciary duty meaning. You should digger further for strict legal context.
2. 過失 is the generally acceptable for "negligence"